# when to call notifyDataChanged() on childview in ExpandableListview android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

In `ExpandableListview` I using multiple `Group Header` with multiple `Child view`

The first `Group Header` text "Shape" that has childview containing `imageview` and `checkbox`

Initially I get 6 fresh `shape names` in `childview` when I scroll this ,the name repeats (not getting remaining 6 fresh names)

ExpandableListviewActivity.java

```
listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), shape_list);
Log.e("details", "karjeev112 "+shape_list);

@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (error_flag==1) { // If no network
                Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this,"Network Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            else{
                listAdapter=new ExpandableListAdapter(SearchActivity.this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);                      
                expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                expListView.setItemChecked(0, true);
                expListView.setSelected(true);
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                expListView.invalidateViews();
                expListView.requestLayout();

            }

            if (progressDialog!=null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
```

ExpandableListAdapter.java

```
@Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);  
        Log.e("_childText", "karjeevch "+childText);


        int itemType = getChildType(groupPosition,childPosition);      


        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        switch (itemType) {

        case 0:
            viewHolder = null;
            if (convertView==null) {

                viewHolder=new ViewHolder();                
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child_shape, null);
                viewHolder.shape_name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.shape_chk_box);
                viewHolder.img_shape_icon=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_shape);                


                imageLoader.DisplayImage("http://rosycontact.com/shashvat/images/"+childText.toLowerCase()+".png", viewHolder.img_shape_icon);                
                Log.e("shape", "karjeevshp "+childText);
                viewHolder.shape_name.setText(childText);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);               

               final CheckBox shape_name_temp=viewHolder.shape_name;                
               viewHolder.shape_name.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        int id=buttonView.getId();
                        if (id==R.id.shape_chk_box) {

                            if (shape_name_temp.isChecked()==true) {

                                String shape_str=shape_name_temp.getText().toString();
                                All_link.SHAPE_LIST.add(shape_str);
                                Toast.makeText(_context, shape_name_temp.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Log.e("chk_shape", "karjeevch "+shape_name_temp.getText().toString());
                            }
                            else{
                                String shape_str=shape_name_temp.getText().toString();
                                All_link.SHAPE_LIST.remove(shape_str);
                            }
                        }                                                                                           
                    }
                });                                          
            }
            else{
                viewHolder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
            return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the data for the ChildViews in case the convertView is not NULL.Thats why when you scroll the childViews have repetative data.

try setting the data like below.

```
 if (convertView==null) {
    //Inflate a new View only if its null

                    viewHolder=new ViewHolder();                
                    convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child_shape, null);
                    viewHolder.shape_name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.shape_chk_box);
                    viewHolder.img_shape_icon=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_shape);                
    ......}
    ......
    //Put the appropriate data in your Views.

     viewHolder.shape_name.setText(childText);
     ......
    //more code
```

Comment: Can u help me with selector for Expandablelistview ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562051/listview-item-background-via-custom-selector

Comment: Use can use a normal ListSector as explained in the link above and add it to the parent and child layout of the ExpandableListView

Comment: Yes marked .. I have my posted question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28622403/listselector-for-group-header-and-child-layout-in-expandablelistview-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Also do not create a new ExpandableListAdapter in onPostExecute

1.Create a new Adapter in onCreate of you activity.
    2.You can modify the data of your ExpandableListAdapter , i.e listDataHeader and listDataChild by clearing the list and adding the
    appropriate data items to them.
    3.Then you can call notifyDataSetChange() in your onPostExecute.

Comment: Can u help me with this brother  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28622403/listselector-for-group-header-and-child-layout-in-expandablelistview-not-working